# bootstrap4xpages with IE9 in datepicker in edit mode ruins layout

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, xpages

I am using the bootstrap4xpages extension library. I am trying to use the application in IE9. When I have a page in read mode it looks fine, but when I use the datepicker in iE9 and go to edit the document the page layout gets broken and it switched the layout to a mobile page.

What can I do with the layout to prevent this from happening? 
Can I disable the responsiveness on a page? Can I prevent the bsextension library from reading the date picker?

I figure it must be the renderer as the dojo text box operates fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this working in IE9, Yes I know upgrading the browser is the "right" answer. But I needed legacy browser support.

I needed to make a custom theme that extends bootstrap3 with this property.

```
<property>
                <name>styleClass</name>
                <value>#{javascript: var response = facesContext.getExternalContext().getResponse();
                    response.setHeader('X-UA-Compatible', 'IE=9');}</value>
            </property>

            <control>
    <property>
```

I then need to make sure I am running the standard respond.js and html5shiv in the resources.

Reviewing my code it looks like I am also putting this code in the layout of the before render response. Which I need to doublecheck to see if both are required. Not sure if this or the layout is doing the work. But working in ie9 is a total hack anyways.

```
<property>
                <name>styleClass</name>
                <value>#{javascript: var response = facesContext.getExternalContext().getResponse();
                    response.setHeader('X-UA-Compatible', 'IE=9');}</value>
            </property>

            <control>
    <property>
```

If anyone reading this is struggling with legacy browser support, I feel your pain. Remember that it gets better and your company will have to upgrade eventually, just now your apps will be ready.

Answer (score 2):

This likely has nothing to do with XPages but is just about bootstrap support for these browsers. They don't fully support CSS3.

Review this page I think.

http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support

Comment: Understood. Just trying to think if there is a way to get this particular problem undercontrol with an admittedly outdated browser. My hope was that because the problem seemed to be from one particular control that I could use prevent the bootstrap4xpages from picking up the datepicker, or just prevent responsivness in bootstrap 3 somehow. Bootstrap 2.x works fine, but after using 3, it just doesn't look as nice.

Comment: If you must stick with that browser then I would stay with bootstrap 2.x.  That's still in the Boostrap4XPages project I believe.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a need to use the default Datepicker? I use this one and it works well: https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker

Comment: That might work, could you share a piece of code that shows how you use it on a page with a datasource?

Comment: https://github.com/zeromancer1972/FileSilo/blob/master/FileSilo%20ODP/CustomControls/ccFile.xsp
(line 367)

Add a class "datepicker" and set it on your CSJS to react on clicks:

https://github.com/zeromancer1972/FileSilo/blob/master/FileSilo%20ODP/Code/ScriptLibraries/core.js
(line 88)

Answer (score 1):

Short version: upgrade your IE.

Long version:
Bootstrap is designed to work with current and modern browsers. IE9 doesn't qualify for either of these criteria. The current version is IE11 which is 9 month old.

At the release of Bootstrap3 that was the current version and it should work well. You might get it to work with Bootstrap2 (never tried it).

You can't have cutting edge technology with outdated components (interestingly your challenges stem not from XPages but HTML, CSS and IE). Try to mount the tires you have on your current car onto a Ford Model T - or its engine into your car.

Time to have a serious chat with the IT manager :-) let us know if you need help there

Comment: I hear you loud and clear. Its a problem of largeish corporate environment where some applications require older versions of IE. The IT Manager in me wants compatibility in application which has us holding back on browser updates, while the developer in me wants the latest and greatest.

Comment: @stwissel Bootstrap v3 supports IE8+. Read the docs: getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support

Comment: @cvrebert - in theory, and to a great extend - yes

Comment: (Not disagreeing that upgrading is the far superior option though.)